# Spring boot Cacheable annotation with JPA entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I'm trying to caching jpa entity to redis through `@Cacheable` annotation.

[RedisConfig.class]

```java
@Configuration
public class RedisConfig {
    @Value("${spring.redis.host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${spring.redis.port}")
    private int port;

    @Bean
    public RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
        return new LettuceConnectionFactory(host, port);
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<?, ?> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory());
        return redisTemplate;
    }
}
```

[Service layer]

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class RoomQueryService {
    private final RoomRepository roomRepository;

    @Cacheable(value = "search", key = "#code")
    public Room searchRoomByCode(String code) {
        return roomRepository.findByCode(code).orElseThrow(RoomNotFoundException::new);
    }
}
```

When executed above code, it throw below error.

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Cannot serialize; nested exception is org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to serialize object using DefaultSerializer; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DefaultSerializer requires a Serializable payload but received an object of type [slido.slidoclone.room.domain.Room]] with root cause
```

Maybe it caused because DefaultSerializer can't serialize jpa entity class.

So I added below 2 lines to RedisConfig.

```java
        redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());
```

But it throw same error.

After searching about it, I found 2 solutions.

1. Add `implements Serializable` to JPA entity
2. Use cacheManager in `@Cacheable` annotation

I'm curious as to which method is used in production.

Thanks.

Comment: about 1. i would "stick to spec" (in any env): "**If** an entity instance is to be **passed by value as a detached object (e.g., through a remote interface)**, the entity class **must** implement the Serializable interface." https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-entities-serializable -> https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I think your `RedisTemplate` isn't actually used anywhere. You'd have to supply a `RedisCacheConfiguration` instead (taken from ["Spring Boot Cache with Redis"](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-redis-cache)):

```java
@Bean
public RedisCacheConfiguration cacheConfiguration() {
    return RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
            .entryTtl(Duration.ofMinutes(60))
            .disableCachingNullValues()
            .serializeValuesWith(SerializationPair.fromSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add annotation @EnableCaching and see the effect.

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@EnableCaching
public class RoomQueryService {
private final RoomRepository roomRepository;

@Cacheable(value = "search", key = "#code")
public Room searchRoomByCode(String code) {
    return 
  roomRepository.findByCode(code).orElseThrow(RoomNotFoundException::new);
  }
 }
```